# How to write a multi line macro in ~/.lldbinit?

Tags: syntax, macros, multiline, lldb

I want to write this macro in `~/.lldbinit`:

```
command regex pxml 's/(.+)/p xmlElemDump(stdout, %1, xmlDocGetRootElement(%1))/' -h "Dump the contents of an XML tree."
```

But it is too long and I want to break it into multi lines like this:

```
command regex pxml
    's/(.+)/p xmlElemDump(stdout, %1, xmlDocGetRootElement(%1))/'
    -h "Dump the contents of an XML tree."
```

or

```
command regex pxml\
    's/(.+)/p xmlElemDump(stdout, %1, xmlDocGetRootElement(%1))/'\
    -h "Dump the contents of an XML tree."
```

Unfortunately both of them cause this error:

```
Enter one of more sed substitution commands in the form: 's/<regex>/<subst>/'.
Terminate the substitution list with an empty line.
```

How can I break the macro into multi lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lldb doesn't have a continuation character.  That would be tricky in some of the free-form commands, particularly the "print" command.  But would be useful in these cases.  Feel free to file a bug requesting this with the lldb/llvm bug tracker: https://llvm.org/bugs/.

In most cases where a command has a few options, then takes a set of inputs, the command can enter a little mini-editor for the set of inputs. This is true for `command regex`.  So in command line lldb, you would see:

```
(lldb) command regex whatever -h "some help" -s "some syntax"
Enter one of more sed substitution commands in the form: 's/<regex>/<subst>/'.
Terminate the substitution list with an empty line.
> s/First/Replacement/ 
> s/Second/Replacement/ 
>
```

The `command source` function that also reads the .lldbinit works by feeding the command file as a stream to the interpreter.  So you need to mock up what the command line does:

```
command regex whatever -h "some help" -s "some syntax"
s/First/Replacement/
s/Second/Replacement/
```

That's not quite right, there has to be a blank line in the input file after the last substitution to terminate the substitutions, but I can't convince this markup to include it in the code block. But you get the idea.

Comment: Note, if your substitution regex command starts getting really long, it might be time to think about writing it as a Python command instead.  Instructions for that are here: http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But writing the macro in that mini-editor way and adding a blank line after the last substitution in `~/.lldbinit`, and using it to be interpreted while starting lldb or sourcing it with `command source ~/.lldbinit` will produce that error again. It seems that lldb does not recognize blank lines in sourcing as the end of input.

Comment: When I do this, I get that text about "Enter one or more..." printed out, but the regex command actually was created and works as expected.  Did you check that the command worked, or assume from the output that it didn't?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Messages are printed but commands are working. Thank you for the description :)

Answer (score 2):

I write aliases in a .py file and import it to `~/.lldbinit`.
In python file, we can use continuation character.

e.g.)

you would save the following code as something.py

```
def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand("command regex pos 's/(.*)?-op?(.*)/ exp -l swift -O  %2 -- %1/'\
                                              's/(.*)/ exp -l swift -O -- %1/'")
```

write this in `~/.lldbinit`

```
command script import <path>/something.py
```